# Problems with wireless connection using Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have a Dell Laptop Precision M6800 running Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS and have problems to recognize my wireless card. it is a dual boot machine with Windows 8.1 in which the wireless card works fine. In Linux, the wireless lamp is not even on. He is some relevant output.

> lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GLM [Quadro K4100M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
11:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8520 (rev 01)
```

lshw -c network

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: f0:1f:af:56:21:ca
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.1.4-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=192.168.0.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 memory:f7a00000-f7a1ffff memory:f7a3d000-f7a3dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f5a00000-f5a07fff memory:f5800000-f59fffff
```

iwconfig

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:1f:af:56:21:ca  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f21f:afff:fe56:21ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:223640 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:151245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:313133346 (313.1 MB)  TX bytes:14012600 (14.0 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7a00000-f7a20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7720 (7.7 KB)  TX bytes:7720 (7.7 KB)
```

Thus, wlan0 is not even seen.

I have installed already firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details about your wireless device from the terminal command lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: I have exactly the same problem: (
I've tried different methods given on pages ... Sometimes the wifi connection works, but after reboot again no longer works ...

Answer (score 1):

There are drivers for your dell laptop found [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=53R21&fileId=3333875845&osCode=1204A&productCode=precision-m4800-workstation&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS). I don't have a dell laptop but I have the same broadcom chip and this worked for me.

What I did:

1) First download the .tar.gz file from the [link](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=53R21&fileId=3333875845&osCode=1204A&productCode=precision-m4800-workstation&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS) above.

2) Then in main folder install (double click in GUI or use `dpkg -i` in cmd) linux-headers-3.5.0-30.51~precise1_all.deb (the 12.1MB one).

3) Next go back and install the bt-dw1550-firware_0.1_all.deb

4) Install bcmwl kernel source by: `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

5) Finally restart and WiFi should be working like normal

Not managed to get the integrated bluetooth to work only just this second got WiFi to work and came across this thread as I was searching for help. If anyone finds a way to get bluetooth to work please do tell! :)

Answer (score 0):

Installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` should bring the correct dkms source and `wl.ko` module, but I'm using raring kernel 3.8.x and `bcmwl-kernel-source 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.2` crashed my machine.

Newer source from broadcom solved that problem.
Download source from here: 
http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

And follow the instructions in here:
http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt

I downloaded this version:
hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_141.tar.gz
And now I have wlan working on my Z87 Extreme6/ac motherboard.

For completeness sake I'll add here that I had follow and installed b43 firmware from http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/no_net_install_bcm43xx_firmware.tar.bz2 as instructed at
https://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/wireless/484106-broadcom-firmware-needed-b43-but-i-have-no-network-easierwork-around.html before I found bcmwl sources.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work reliably using the source code download either; sometimes it would connect but after a reboot I had to go through a random game of unloading and reloading the wl module.
What I did instead was install the LTS kernel from saucy and manually install the bcmwl-kernel-source package for saucy (it's at 6.30 in saucy, as opposed to 6.20 in precise-updates). So far, this seems stable.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-saucy
wget http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Make sure to remove all your old wl module stuff first (`sudo dkms remove b43b1/6.30.223.141 --all` or `sudo dkms remove bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.141 --all` replacing the version with the appropriate one) before installing the new one if you tried any of the other methods.